# Why is sodium zincate two sodium ions and two oxygen ions but only one zinc ion?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, redox

$2$NaOH + Zn ---> Na<sub>2</sub>ZnO<sub>2</sub>+H<sub>2</sub>

I have always been fascinated by this reaction because it never made sense to me why sodium zincate has such a strange composition. Why does it have two sodium and oxygen ions but only one zinc ion? What is really happening here?

Comment: Who says it has oxygen and zinc ions? BTW, it is more commonly $\ce{2 Na+ + [Zn(OH)4]^2-}$

Comment: Your answer is false.

Comment: Care to respect the community rules? BTW, you confuse answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction of metallic zinc $\ce{Zn}$ with $\ce{NaOH}$ may happen in the two successive reactions :

1. Oxidation of $\ce{Zn}$ from $0$ to the usual +$2$ values in a redox reaction due to the extremely rare $\ce{H+}$ ions present in basic solutions
   $$\ce{Zn + 2 H^+ -> Zn^{2+} + H2}$$
2. Reaction of zinc ions $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ with $\ce{OH^-}$ according to one of the two following equivalent equations :
   $$\ce{Zn^{2+}  +  4 OH- ->  ZnO2^{2-} + 2H2O} $$
   $$\ce{Zn^{2+}  +  4 OH-  ->  [Zn(OH)4]^{2-}}$$
   as the final zincate ion may be witten $\ce{ZnO2^{2-}}$ or $\ce{[Zn(OH)4]^{2-}}$ according to the chosen handbook. Both formula are found in the literature.

Comment: Shouldn´t the reduction of zinc in basic media be written as $\ce{Zn + 2H2O -> Zn^2+ 2OH^- }$?

Comment: @PAEP. It is of course possible to replace my first equation by the following one, which is an oxidation of zinc (and not a reduction) similar to yours : $\ce{Zn + 2 H2O -> Zn^{2+} + 2OH- + H2}$

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Your question was : Why does it have two sodium and oxygen ions but only one zinc ion? The reason is that one $\ce{Zn}$ atom must react with two $\ce{O}$ atoms. If one $\ce{Zn}$ atom reacts with only one oxygen atom, it does not produce an ion. It forms an oxide, which is $\ce{ZnO}$, but this oxide is not an ion and does not contain any sodium atom.